# how to retain drop down selected values after form submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

how to retain drop down selected values after form submitted? i have a form which is submit via `onchange` but problem is that when i select value from drop down then form is submitted but drop down values struck on `Select Option`

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function getdropdownvalue(){
var e = document.getElementById("size");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
```

**Drop Down Select**

```
<form name="size" id="size">
<select style="background-color:#CCC" name="size[]" 
id="size"  onchange="this.form.submit();getdropdownvalue();" >
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="XL">XL</option>
</select></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to run `getdropdownvalue();` before submitting the form:

`<select style="background-color:#CCC" name="size[]" id="size" onchange="getdropdownvalue();this.form.submit();" >`

To make sure the drop-down value is retained, submit the form to an invisible `iframe`. This allows the form to be submitted without refreshing the page:

```
<form target="invisible">...</form>
<iframe name="invisible" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

Comment: after form page is refresh or reload so i want if page reload then i want get back dropdown value which is selected before submit form

Comment: @FarhanDharsi I see... Is there anything on the submit page? You don't have a `form action` in the question.

Comment: i used onchange="this.form.submit(); on dropdown